# How do you read and process a line that can have multiple objects on one line JAVA

Tags: java, csv

I want to read a CSV file for a number of elements that can either be metal or non-metal and each line in the CSV file can have multiple elements. If it has multiple elements, all rows of the file will have that amount of elements. A valid line will look like:

```
<symbol,name,atomNum,mass,other/><symbol,name,atomNum,mass,other/>
```

where other is a character if its a nonmetal and double if its a metal. This is what I have done so far and am not sure how to read in multiple element objects on the line

```
public static void readValues(String fileName)
{
    if (!constructed)
    {
        FileInputStream fileStrm = null;
        InputStreamReader rdr;
        BufferedReader bufRdr;
        String line;
        int lineNum;
        try
        {
            fileStrm = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            rdr = new InputStreamReader(fileStrm);
            bufRdr = new BufferedReader(rdr);
            lineNum = 0;
            line = bufRdr.readLine();
            while(line != null)
            {
                lineNum++;
                elements[lineNum - 1] = processElements(line);
                line = bufRdr.readLine();
                System.out.println(elements);
            }
            fileStrm.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            if(fileStrm != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    fileStrm.close();
                    constructed = true;
                }
                catch (IOException ex2)
                {
                }
            }
            System.out.print("error in file processing: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private static Element processElements(String line)
{
    char chr;
    Element element;
    String[] lineArray = line.split(",");
    if(lineArray[4] == chr)
    {
        element = new NonMetal();
        elements.setState(lineArray[4]);
    }
    else
    {
        element = new Metal();
        element.setConduct(Double.parseDouble(lineArray[4]));
    }
    element.setSymbol(lineArray[0]);
    element.setName(lineArray[1]);
    element.setAtomNum(Integer.parseInt(lineArray[2]));
    element.setMass(Double.parseDouble(lineArray[3]));
    return elements;
}
```

I have a super element class and two subclasses, metal and nonmetal, each containing the standard methods for a class

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to identify a group between `<` and `/>`, while processing the line.

```
<(\w+),(\w+),(\w+),(\w+),(\w+)\/>
```

https://regex101.com/r/bKnYJZ/1/

```
String line = "<symbol,name,atomNum,mass,other/><symbol,name,atomNum,mass,other/>";
String regex = "<(\\w+),(\\w+),(\\w+),(\\w+),(\\w+)\\/>";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex)
                         .matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
  System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
  System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
  System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
  System.out.println(matcher.group(5));
}
```

You could put this code into your `processElements` method to identify each element between `<` `/>`

Aside of your problem, I suggest the use of [try-resource-close](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for an easier and shorter resource handling.

```
try(FileInputStream fileStrm = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    InputStreamReader rdr = new InputStreamReader(fileStrm);
    BufferedReader bufRdr = new BufferedReader(rdr))
{
  // here your code and no need to take care of resource closing...
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    System.out.print("error in file processing: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This method does seem to do the job, I just have to familiarise myself with regex. One problem though is that on a line it is possible to have n elements, meaning it could have 3,4,8,9 elements on a single line. How do I account for that? I'm thinking you need to count the amount of "<" characters which initiate the start of an element and use that count to create an appropriate amount of elements